# Visual Studio : semi-automatic way move implementation from .cpp to .h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, resharper, visual-assist

In Reshaper, there is a tool to move implementation from `.h` to `.cpp` easily (with a few click).

Is there any way to move the implementation from `.cpp` to `.h` easily?   (The opposite way)
I am a bit tired of `ctrl+c` `ctrl+v` the source.

I expect a solution in form of a short instruction about Visual Studio 2015 shortcut/hotkey, resharper, visual assistX, or (less preferable) some plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Assist has a command called "Move Implementation to Header File" and is documented [here](https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W702).